# Write value from one column to the next column then to the next column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a value in an Excel column to other columns.

Say something like
`A1 then B1 then C1`

and then again
`A2 then B2 then C2`

It should all happen dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the value of each cell, starting at `A1` through `C1`, then moving to the next line, you can use two for loops, nested:

```
Sub writeSomething()
     Dim intMaxRow as Integer, intRow as Integer
     Dim intMaxCol as Integer, intCol as Integer

     intMaxRow = 10
     intMaxCol = 3

     For intCol = 1 to intMaxCol
         For intRow = 1 to intMaxRow
             Sheet1.Cells(intRow, intCol).value = "Writing to cell at position " & intRow & ", " & intCol
         Next intRow
     Next intCol

End Sub
```

That will write the cell position to each cell from `A1` through `C10` moving right to left, top to bottom.